# RegEx Notepad++ Search and Extract

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am looking for the RegEx search string to extract a specific entry in a single row.

Example is

```
{"version":"264599-1-0","exportPath":"Site Management/Site Set-up/Delegation of Authority/Delegation of Authority Log_Jordan, Fiona_12Oct2021_v1.0.pdf","exportTimestamp"
```

I am looking to find and export everything that is  "exportPath":"*" in Notepad++.

The row is quite large and was an export from a database.  The path after the "exportPath":"varying lengths" are varying lengths.  I'm just trying to find the correct RegEx string to find, and the proper string to replace, extracting it on it's own line.
Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] and provide an example showing how it looks **after** the replacement

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"exportPath":".+?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"exportPath":"      # literally
.+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
"                   # quote
(*SKIP)             # skip this match
(*FAIL)             # and considere the match has failled
   |                   # OR
.                   # any character but newline
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find and export everything that is "exportPath": "*" in Notepad++ you can use the following way (when the attribute is a one liner):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- **Find what:** `"exportPath":".*\"`
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd> to check the result
- <kbd>Copy marked Text</kbd> to another text file

[image]